# column not allowed here,

Tags: sql, sqlcommand

```
CREATE table Patient (
    Pat_number  Number (30),
    file_no Number (30),
    Id_Card_No Number (30),
    Pat_name varchar(30),
    Date_of_Birth Number (30),
    Blood_symbol varchar(30),
);
```

Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Patient (Pat_Number, file_no, Id_Card_No, Pat_name,
 Date_of_Birth, Blood_symbol) 
VALUES (4352, 522, 1342876, "AhmadMahmoudAbuawad", 19800504 ,"A");
```

Comment: sql uses ' instead of "

Comment: what exactly is your doubt

Answer (score 0):

Sql uses single quotes for strings instead of double quotes

```
INSERT INTO Patient (Pat_Number, file_no, Id_Card_No, 
Pat_name,Date_of_Birth,Blood_symbol) 
VALUES (4352, 522, 1342876, "AhmadMahmoudAbuawad", 19800504 ,"A");

INSERT INTO Patient (Pat_Number, file_no, Id_Card_No, 
Pat_name,Date_of_Birth,Blood_symbol) 
VALUES (4352, 522, 1342876, 'AhmadMahmoudAbuawad', 19800504 ,'A');
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all , as other users mentioned , you can use `'`  instead of `"` .
but why you are typing your table's fields?
we write table fields only when we want to `insert` a value which is not going in the direction of table creation fields.
I mean when you are inserting values in the order of fields definition you don't need to write the fields of the table.
in this case you can simply do :

```
INSERT INTO Patient  
VALUES (4352, 522, 1342876, 'AhmadMahmoudAbuawad', 19800504 ,'A');
```

Comment: amshakur, It is actually very good practice to type the column name always in your query. If you ever added 1 or more columns later in your table, Your Insert statement will break but if you have all the columns listed insert will work. So it is a standard practice to always list the table columns while doing insert or select.